# Query to get an accumuleted time (in seconds) when a value is greater than x

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have simple table with measure result:

```
datetime            | p_power
------------------------------
2012-11-25 19:57:58 |   60  
2012-11-25 19:58:33 |   300  => start  
2012-11-25 19:59:05 |   350  
2012-11-25 19:59:39 |   400  
2012-11-25 20:00:13 |   50   => stop = t1  
2012-11-25 20:02:26 |   50  
2012-11-25 20:02:59 |   340  => start  
2012-11-25 20:04:07 |   310  
2012-11-25 20:06:37 |   60   => stop = t2  
2012-11-25 20:07:02 |   340
```

How to do a query in order to get a accumuleted time (sum of `t1` + `t2` + `tn` in seconds) when `p_power` result is more than 200.

Result expected: xxx seconds.

I'm stuck on it, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear for now: how do you distinguish start/stop rows?

Comment: Start when p_power is greater than 200. stop when it's less than 200. In order to try to make it more clear: I measure the power of a heating device. If the value is less than 200 it's mean that only pumps are working, if it's more, it means that the fuel is consumed. If I am able to count elapsed time when p_power is greater than 200, I can know how many gallon of fuel is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I have understood you right...

The following query calculates the sum of all p_power who are greater (or equal) 200

```
Select Sum(p_power) from your_table
Where p_power >= 200;
```

should give you 2040 (if my brain was calculating right)

Comment: As I've understood — @Thierry wants to summarise time, not powers.